# Online courses for mathematics

Tags: mathematics-education, gm.general-mathematics, online-resources

I'm sorry if I'm posting this in the wrong forum. My background is in biology and medicine. I am looking to re-learn undergraduate-level mathematics, in particular discrete mathematics, calculus, and linear algebra. I did do these courses back in college, but I've since forgotten most of this.

Does anyone know of good **online** college-level courses with problem sets and proctored examinations that can complement working through standard texts?

Thanks!

Ansel

Comment: MIT Opencourseware has good online lectures and problem sets, but no proctored examinations.

Comment: Hi Ansel Lim, and welcome to the MathOverflow: this question is out of topic here, however this is also a really really important question. How to improve the personal knowledge and culture in order to add an important branch to your higher education? The common answer, at least in Italy, has been "Stage" until now: however, not all higher education institutes offer stages on scientific topics like mathematics physics and engineering. Administrative/management courses are yet more fashionable.

Comment: This is better asked at [https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/). In any case, I suggest your best sources may be either [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) or [edX](https://www.edx.org).